# Javascript error:object Required

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I hav a Dropdown,Panel1,panel2 and a button on my page.

Inside Panel1 there is gridview1 and similarly in panel2 we have gridview2

But i get an error in javascript onload saying "Object Required" in the below mentioned line
 if (parseInt($('#<%= gvSelectedInstitutelist.ClientID %>').length) == 0)

The error is thrown when grid has no data..or the length is zero..

 Error is:"Object Expected"

Comment: Are you sure it's the grid that is not available, and not one of the children?  Break the line into individual parts and do an "alert", or check the individual parts through FireBug or F12 in IE/Chrome

Answer (score 0):

Put the javascript in your html file.
After this, use jQuery if possible.

/edit: I've started an webforms project to test this: Contents are one asp: panel containing one GridView element. I've created one dataset with one row of dummy data and pasted the script just below the aspx code.

```
<asp:Content runat="server" ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
<asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server">
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">
    </asp:GridView>
</asp:Panel>
<script type = "text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function () {
        if ($('#<%= GridView1.ClientID %>').length == 0) {
            $('#<%= Panel1.ClientID %>').hide();
            console.log("Length == 0");
        }
   });
```

Code behind:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("Name");
        dt.Columns.Add("Branch");
        dt.Columns.Add("Officer");
        dt.Columns.Add("CustAcct");
        dt.Columns.Add("Grade");
        dt.Columns.Add("Rate");
        dt.Columns.Add("OrigBal");
        dt.Columns.Add("BookBal");
        dt.Columns.Add("Available");
        dt.Columns.Add("Effective");
        dt.Columns.Add("Maturity");
        dt.Columns.Add("Collateral");
        dt.Columns.Add("LoanSource");
        dt.Columns.Add("RBCCode");

        dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "James Bond, LLC", 120, "Garrison Neely", "123 3428749020", 35, "6.000", "$24,590", "$13,432",
        "$12,659", "12/13/21", "1/30/27", 55, "ILS", "R"});

        ds.Tables.Add(dt);

        GridView1.DataSource = ds;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
```

This totally works for me. If the dummydata is commented out in code behind, I get Length < 2 returned. If I use the dummy data the returned value in console is Length > 2.

please post your whole aspx + js code here.

Comment: hi thanks 4 replying i used ur method but i am still getting the same error..object required.

Comment: recheck my js code please. I have reedited it, so it runs completly on jQuery. You do not need `.children[0]` anymore. This should eliminate your Object errors.
And please update your original code, so we can properly see your changes and the problems you might have with it.

Comment: i hav almost pasted my entire code.please have a look and now i get the error as "Object Expected"

Comment: change  `document.getElementById("ctl00_rightContainer_ContentTable1_panSelectedInstitutes").style.display = 'none';`
to: `$('#<%= panSelectedInstitutes.ClientID %>').hide();`

You have looked up the ID of your objects in your client side Code. This won't work. Access your objects like panels or gridviews via `yourobject.ClientID`. this way you can access them and manipulate them via javascript.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24512/discussion-between-serv-and-user1274646)